# How to do a complex phrase keyword search in solr

Tags: solr, solr4

Can somebody please tell me how can i do a complex phrase search in solr, for eg: if the user enters "and MAC F1:65" , the results should have "and MAC F1:65" in them, this seems to be working fine for MAC addresses starting with F1:65 (mac address is  F1:65:CA:F0:00:00 ), if i pass the following query.

```
display_string:"and MAC F1:65"
```

But if want to search only a part of MAC address, suppose my query is "and MAC 65:CA", the above command does not work even if i escape the semi-colon, I tried passing wild cards too, but they don't work either.

Also, what is the meaning of this:

> "msg": "no field name specified in query and no default specified via 'df' param"

I am a beginner and i have spent two days trying to fix this, do i need a plugin  to do this?

EDIT: It works if i break up the query into `(+and +MAC +65\:CA)` with dismax plugin, but is there no other way Lucene query would be able to do this?

Here is the schema of the core:

```
<schema name="autoSolrSchema" version="1.5">
<types>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TextField" name="TextField">
<analyzer>
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TrieDateField" name="TrieDateField"/>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.UUIDField" name="UUIDField"/>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TrieIntField" name="TrieIntField"/>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.StrField" name="StrField"/>
</types>

<fields>...
```

Comment: Can you provide FieldType declaration used for index and query phase?

Comment: Here it is `<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="display_string" stored="true" type="TextField"/>` i didn't understand what you mean by query phase? I am not passing any field type parameter for query phase..

Comment: Can you provide the definition for display_string?

Comment: display_string is a column in a cassandra keyspace of text type...is that what you wanted to know? I am working with solr on cassandra/dse..

Comment: No. Your `schema.xml` should have a FieldType tag declaration which define the tokenizers and set of filters to process this field before indexing. For example: text_general is one which uses `StandardTokenizerFactory` and some StopwordFilter. [text_general](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Field+Type+Definitions+and+Properties)

Comment: I have edited the fieldtype declaration in the question, please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have two distinct questions:

Whether `display_string` hits depends on the definition of the field display_string, and how it's being processed. If it's a `string` (StrField), you won't be able to hit anything in the field at all. If it's a `text_general` (which is one of the default types supplied in the example config), 'down' and 'new' should give hits at least, while '65:CA' also should work - albeit there might be differences here based on how the field is processed.

The error message `no field name specified in query and no default specified via 'df' param` means exactly that - you didn't include a field name in your query, and Solr doesn't know what field to search by default, since there's no `df` parameter supplied either. `foo:bar` searches for the value `bar` in the field `foo`, but if you just provide `bar`, Solr doesn't know what field to search unless `df` is present (or the defaultSearchField in the configuration, which was the Old Way of doing that).

If you're using the (e)dismax query parser, you can also use the `qf` parameter to search several fields at once, and include weighting between the different fields. `qf=display_string macaddr` will search both the `display_string` and the `macaddr` field.

Comment: `display_string:+down +new "65:CA"~`  works but it also shows me values not having mac address 65:CA, when I give sorting with time stamp descending option. Is that what you meant by "while '65:CA' also should work - albeit there might be differences here based on how the field is processed"?

Comment: It seems to be running perfectly with dismax plugin on the solr server interface, how do I write is as a query?

Comment: Just use `defType=dismax` or, depending on which library used, set the query processor / type there. Should be well documented.

Comment: Well yeah, i saw it, but again I am getting another problem, dismax seems to be working fine on the interface; in the qf field on the interface i was using `id:4 AND gr_id: (0  1  2)  AND display_string` and in the q field i typed `+down +new +0f\:cd` which gave me correct results, but i want to construct a solr query since i am using solr on datastax/cassandra. So, when i use `{!defType=dismax mm=100%}  id:4 AND gr_id: (0  1  2)  AND display_string:(+down +new +0f\:cd)` as a query i get no result on the interface.

Comment: The qf field is meant to have field names, not queries. Use debugQuery to see how your query is parsed, remove parts to see where the match stops and if you're going to search each field for values prefixed with fieldname, you probably don't need dismax.

Comment: I dont know what am i doing wrong or if this is a bug but when i search with query without dsmax `display_string: (+down +new +65\:CA)` i get the desired results but when i do a different query `display_string: (+detected +interfering +0f\:cd)` i get no results whereas, if pass the same query in dismax i get results! So i thought maybe i was suppsosed to use dismax.

Comment: It's impossible to say without seeing your actual query, but you might get weird results because of the space after :, meaning that the query is performed against the default field instead of the field you've provided. Use debugQuery to see what the resulting Lucene query actually is.

Comment: I have not specified a default field in the schema. I will update my question to explain it better since i have made a few changes to my query.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `double quotes` in the term query, it consider it as phrase and all the terms from query should be present in the same order as they are in query. That is why, you are able to match/search the mac address when you provide the prefix of the mac address.

The second case, using `+` operator. The `+` operator requires that the term after the `+` symbol exist somewhere in a the field. So now it not dependent on the order of the term, term must be present in the field. you don't need dismax plugin to achieve this feature. You need to use `+` operator for `must` present terms.

Other way could be using (Edge)N-Gram Filter for generating different tokens and indexing them. In my opinion, that is not required for you. It will also increase your index size.

You also might want to understand what you analyzers are doing while indexing and querying the data.

**Data:** machine address (00:1R:54:C8:CD:30)

```
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TextField" name="TextField">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

The `StandardTokenizer` tokenizer splits the text field into tokens, treating whitespace and punctuation as delimiters. The `LowerCaseFilter` lowercases the letters in each token. So when you index you data, it split the mac address into six separate token and indexes them. Same happens for the query phase.
[image]

---

I found that, `StandardTokenizer` doesn't create tokens in some case by splitting the parts of mac add. e.g. the `CA:F0` are not split in two tokens.
[image]

Please try with the below configuration:

```
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TextField" name="TextField_Pattern">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern=":"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

This is using `PatternTokenizer` instead of `StandardTokenizer`. The `PatternTokenizer` will always generate the tokens by splitting parts of mac address.
[image]

Here is an example of partial search. I have taken alternate parts of the mac address and searched.
[image]

Comment: I do not understand one thing though, if i run the following query: `display_string:(+and +MAC +65\:CA)` i get the desired result, but if the query is `display_string:(+and +MAC +CA\:F0)`, i get no result (MAC address is F1:65:CA:F0:00:00). Also the query works if the last two parts of mac addresses are entered.

Comment: can you try enabling the debug mode and run the query. use `&debugQuery=true`. This is will provide the detailed information about how the query is executed against the index. The the query url in browser and check the bottom of the page for debug results.

Comment: okay, here are the 2 results i had, i can see there is a difference in the parsed queries.. http://postimg.org/image/smv4z4g5v/ and http://postimg.org/image/tqdgt8zlt/ , but the syntax i passed was same as you can see!

Comment: By the way, i ran a different query and for a different MAC address. Also, is every word in the text files tokenized by solr?

Comment: All the data/text passed to a field is tokenized and indexed. That is why analyzer sequence is important and defines how your data will be indexed. You should index your data by keeping in mind, how it will be queried later by users/application.

Comment: How can i check if the middle portions of MAC are indexed or not...because the query is working for the first two parts of the MAC but not the middle parts of MAC.

Comment: Login to solr admin UI. Localhost:8983/solr/corename. Select the core and go to analysis section. You can find the behavior of your 'display_string' field. I have pasted a screen shot already in my answer. Please check.

Comment: Yes okay, but i am still befuddled as to why partial MAC search is not working.. by the way, in the picture/analyse section, field index displays how the text will be stored right?

Comment: Yes. Please check, I have added more information. Hope it will solve the partial search issue.

Comment: Great. Did you use the configuration provided in the answer or solved it in some other way?

Comment: I did not try your solution because I will have to reindex but i see the problem now, http://i.imgur.com/9M17MdF.png and this http://i.imgur.com/OrH7Upy.png (strange it works for one mac but not other!)